# Count Specific Values in Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

If I had a column in a dataframe, and that column contained two possible categorical variables, how do I count how many times each variable appeared?

So e.g, how do I count how many of the participants in the study were male or female?

I've tried value_counts, groupby, len etc, but seem to be getting it wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and with the code for the incorrect results, and desired output from this sample data?

Answer (score 2):

Supposing that "gender" is the column of the dataframe,we can count the occurences of the categorical data using

```
df['gender'].value_counts().to_dict()
```

it will give us the count of the two class of data in dictionary format

```
{"male":4,"female":5}
```

if you want it in list format then

```
df['gender'].value_counts().tolist()
```

output will be

```
[4,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `len([x for x in df["Sex"] if x == "Male")`. This iterates through the `Sex` column of your dataframe and determines whether an element is "Male" or not. If it is, it is appended to a list via list comprehension. The length of that list is the number of Males in your dataframe.

Comment: You can similarly use `sum(x == "male" for x in data["sex"])`

Comment: Not only should you not iterate through a dataframe in python, if it can be avoided, but your syntax is correct.

Comment: That's even better!

Comment: Well, it's better, but it doesn't use any pandas methods, so is likely to be much slower than a vectorized approach.